# Workflow Predictably but Bizarrely ending in "Stopped" status

Tags: 2007, workflow, permissions

Using WSS 3.0 running on SBS2008. I have an Infopath form library, to which I have used SharePoint Designer 2007 to attach a custom workflow. It's a pretty normal workflow which updates a property in another list based on a lookup.

I have two users, call them Jane and John. Jane is a member of several SP groups, one of which has Full Control permissions. John is a member of a couple of SP groups, one of which has Contribute permissions.

I have 2 workstations, lets call them W1 and W2.  Both are on the local area network and connect to the SP site via Internet Explorer 7 via http://example/.

I have contradictory observations:

1. When John adds an item to the library while working from W2, the workflow is initiated but goes to Stopped status, and the other list is not updated.

   When John adds an item to the library while working from W1, the workflow completes successfully.

   When Jane adds an item to the library while working on EITHER W1 or W2, the workflow completes successfully.

So, it can't be John's permissions, because John is able to fire the workflow successfully (when working from some workstations). And Jane can do the workflow from anywhere, so the W2 workstation itself is configured to allow the workflows to be initiated.

I cannot seem to find any aspect of SP groups or users or permissions which would affect a user's ability to initiate workflow from one workstation but not another.  Am I looking at some Active Directory / Windows Domain permissions issue here? Has anyone seen this kind of issue where Workflow execution ends in Stopped status, but only for some users, and only when they are sitting in particular chairs?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks for reading.

Anonymous Darryl.

Comment: You need to check your SharePoint ULS logs. The problem will be shown in your ULS logs (if properly configured). My guess is that John is probably logged in with a different account on W1/W2 so you should double check that (logoff/logon to SharePoint).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ben and Tony.

I can't give a detailed technical explanation of the cause of the problem, but the resolution involved looking at the Windows Domain group memberships of John and Jane. By assigning some domain group memberships to John which I found on Jane's user in Active Directory, the bizarre workflow problems stopped.

I made absolutely no changes to the SharePoint site, or the SharePoint users or groups.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how authentication is handled with the browser but I've confused SharePoint before logging into and out of Sharepoint without closing the browser.  I've noticed that it gives the appearance of being logged in correctly.  But after navigating to another page it has reverted back to the initial user.

Could it be stored in history or cache of the browser? See if you can reproduce while logging off and then closing browser.